# Creating model with nested attributes on rails 4 without fields_for, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, fields-for

I have 2 models

1) Project

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks

  validates :priority, presence: true
  validates_date :due_date, :after => lambda {Date.current}
  validates_length_of :name, minimum: 5, maximum: 40
  validates_length_of :description, minimum: 10, maximum: 200
end
```

2) Tasks (which belogs to Project)

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, dependent: :destroy

  validates_length_of :name, minimum: 3, maximum: 50
end
```

My controller:

```
   def create
      @project = Project.new(project_params)
      @project.save!
      redirect_to projects_path   
  end

  def new   
    @project = Project.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :due_date, :priority, 
    tasks_attributes: [:name])
  end
```

When I hit the submit button in the form, I can see the request with the nested attribute (the **task**) comes in, so it's saved, correctly, however, only the project is saved, not the task.

I realized that I'm not using the field_for (because I generate it via Javascript, in runtime).

Someone know how to solve this situation?

EDIT:

I've tried `project.tasks.build` into the new action, but the behaviour stands.

The Request that reaches the create action is:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"GItsCNKllmEEYnhihDLx9QRuObWPNL4qwZBKt56Yss0=",
"project"=>{"name"=>"werwfeb3b33b",
"description"=>"rb3rb3rb3rb3rb",
"due_date"=>"2014-01-21",
"priority"=>"2"},
"tasks"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"2e2ev"}}}
```

And the javascript (coffeescript) function code that produces the runtime field "name" of the task model is:

```
AddTaskComponent = ->  
  numberOfTasks++
  $('.tasks').append("<div id='TaskTextField" + numberOfTasks + "' class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon'>Nome" +
  "</span><input type='text' id='taskname" + numberOfTasks + "' name='tasks[" + (numberOfTasks - 1) + "][name]' class='form-control' placeholder='Insira o nome da tarefa'></div>")
```

Answer (score 1):

You nearly have it... your form is returning a params hash that includes, among other parameters:

```
"tasks"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"2e2ev"}}
```

but what you should be returning is

```
"tasks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"2e2ev"}}
```

so you can probably see immediately where to change your javascript to construct the properly formatted params hash. The "name" attribute of the input field must be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating `@project` with your params prior to saving it, so it's just saving the new instance you created in `new`. Once you resolve that, I think you also have to allow nested attributes as described in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: I did it, and still don't get the nested attributes inside my db, only the projects.

Comment: Can you update your code to reflect the new version of `create`?

Comment: Yes, I already did it. Now the create action has the new and the save together.

Comment: Would you mind also updating your `Project` class definition to show how you've allowed nested attributes?

Comment: Edited! As you can see I've used the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks`, so the project can accept the task as a nested attribute.

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine. Next, I would post the params as they are coming across and the results of your `project_params` call.

Comment: Peter, I edited the code. Maybe the problem is with the input generated via javascript? Note that I used the name parameter in the input tag like that: `name='tasks[numberofthetask][name]'`.

Thank you for reaching so far to help in this issue!

Comment: You're still not showing the results of your `project_params` call, which should indicate that the task attributes aren't making it through the `permit` call. I'm not strong enough on my HTML to find the problem with your javascript, but you're tasks attributes are coming through as a hash at the top level rather than an array.

Comment: There's a specific command or call so I can se the project_params?

Comment: Just include a `puts project_params` in your `create` method.

Comment: Exactly as I mentioned.
`"tasks"=>{"0"=>"TEST!"}`

Comment: I don't understand why the `:name` in `[:name]` didn't filter out the `"TEST!"`, but after looking at section 4.5.3 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html, it appears that the hash with `"0"` key is fine, but that you need to have a hash for the value. That is, you need `{name: "TEST!"}` instead of just `"TEST!"`. If that doesn't work, I'm stumped. BTW, I assume that `puts project_params` put out more than one what you just showed and that you only shared `"tasks" => ...` part of it.

Comment: Sorry, I cant edit the comment anymore, but the hash is correctly printed out as:
`"tasks"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"TEST!"}`, inside the project request's hash.

I can't figure out what I'm missing. =s